# Centering list content

Tags: html, css, list, nav, centering

Why isn't my list content totally centered in its container? I used **text-aline: center** in the `#nav` div but it seems as if it might still be taking the bullets into account even though I made them invisible with **list-style-type:none**. I've attached a screenshot.

[image: Wikiversity Web Design/CSS challenge]

Here's the HTML:

```html
<div id="nav">
    <h2>Sonnet Index</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Book #1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Book #2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Book #3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Book #4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Book #5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#nav {
    background-color: #ACCCFF;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 410px;
    text-align: center;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

bydefault `ul` take `60px padding` from left, you can set `padding-left:0` for doing this.

```
ul {
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting the element of your code, left padding was not set to 0px, hence it was shifted towards right, all you had to do was add padding-left:0px;
here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsjain007/aursdgvr/1/)  and the code as well

```css
#nav {
    background-color: #ACCCFF;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 410px;
    text-align: center;
}

ul {
    padding-left: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <h2>Sonnet Index</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Book #1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Book #2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Book #3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Book #4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Book #5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Unordered list has some padding by default you can check it in the inspection tool in your browser. Just remove that padding .Your css will go like..

```
ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   padding-left:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why isn't my list content totally centered in its container?** Well that's because you have `not changed default properties of ul tag` and they are as below,

```
ul  {
display: block;
list-style-type: disc;
margin-top: 1em;
margin-bottom: 1 em;
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
padding-left: 40px; 
}
```

As soon as you change it's `padding:0` your `#nav text-align:center` works fine and align them in center.

```css
#nav {
    background-color: #ACCCFF;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 410px;
    text-align: center;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:0px; /*Add this*/
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <h2>Sonnet Index</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Book #1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Book #2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Book #3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Book #4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Book #5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```